# Compulsary requirement to take and store users photo using Xam.Plugin.Media

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, photo

I have a PCL type app and I'm using the `Xam.Plugin.Media` plugin. I need it to ensure a user submits a photo from the camera before they can continue.

To do this I show the camera page from a button click event and I want to ensure that in case the user cancels out of this that the app launches the camera again, this would repeat until a photograph is stored.

Currenty my app falls in the `onActivityResumed` method of the `MainApplication` file when the user cancels out of the camera

Attached photo of my code, [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvzQE.png).

```
 private async void TakePicture()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "Aceptar");
            }



            file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg",
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
            });

            //IsRunning = true;


            if (file != null)
            {
                ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    return stream;
                });
            }

            IsRunning = false;
        }
```

Comment: do NOT post code as an image.  Take the time to paste and format your code as text.

Comment: Jason has fixed my post

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the fact that it is usually a bit of a UX issue to force a user into anything nowadays, the question still has some merits.

this is the approach that I would consider, it involves recursion.

```
    private async void TakePicture()
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "Aceptar");
        }

        file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg",
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
        });

        //IsRunning = true;

        if (file != null)
        {
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // Recursion - I believe that this would continue until the file is not null, then it would carry on.
            TakePicture();
        }

        IsRunning = false;
    }
```

I can't say I use recursion that often, but I think it might do the trick here.

Comment: My App still fails on the OnActivityResumed .... unhandled exception

 public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
        {
           
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

Comment: That's not related to your camera method then. That's related to whatever you are doing in your 'onActivityResumed' method. Could you please post that method or the full error (stack trace) so we can better help you.